# Generate Rows Between Two Dates, Copying Down The Values in the Remaining Columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

I'm trying to write a script that will look at the issue date and termination date for each policy in a table. I want to be able to take those two dates, create a row for each year in between those two dates, and then fill in the values in the remaining columns.

I've been working with a recursive CTE approach in Redshift and I've got to the point where I can create the annual records. The part I'm stuck on is how to include the other columns in the table and fill each of the created rows with the same information as the row above.

For example, if I start with a record that looks something like

| policy_number | issue_date | termination_date | issue_state | product | plan_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1985-05-26 | 2005-03-02 | CT | ROP | 123456 |

I want to build a table that would look like this

| policy_number | issue_date | termination_date | issue_state | product | plan_code | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1985-05-26 | 2005-03-02 | CT | ROP | 123456 | 1985-05-26 |
| 001 | 1985-05-26 | 2005-03-02 | CT | ROP | 123456 | 1986-05-26 |
| 001 | 1985-05-26 | 2005-03-02 | CT | ROP | 123456 | 1987-05-26 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 001 | 1985-05-26 | 2005-03-02 | CT | ROP | 123456 | 2004-05-26 |
| 001 | 1985-05-26 | 2005-03-02 | CT | ROP | 123456 | 2005-03-02 |

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
WITH RECURSIVE start_dt AS
(
  SELECT MIN(issue_date) AS s_dt -- step 1: grab start date
  FROM myTable
  WHERE policy_number = '001'
  GROUP BY policy_number
),
end_dt AS
(
  SELECT MAX(effective_date) AS e_dt -- step 2: grab the termination date
  FROM myTable
  WHERE policy_number = '001'
  GROUP BY policy_number
),
dates (dt) AS
(
  -- start at the start date
  SELECT s_dt dt -- selectin start date from step 1
  FROM start_dt
  UNION ALL
  -- recursive lines
  SELECT dateadd(YEAR,1,dt)::DATE dt -- converted to date to avoid type mismatch -- adding annual records until the termination date
         FROM dates
  WHERE dt <= (SELECT e_dt FROM end_dt)
  -- stop at the end date
)
SELECT *
FROM dates
```

which yields

| dt |
| --- |
| 1985-05-26 |
| 1986-05-26 |
| 1987-05-26 |
| ... |

How can I include the rest the columns in my table? I'm also open to using a cross join if that would be a better approach. I'm expecting this to generate around 10,000,000 rows, so any optimization would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to replicate rows with interstitial dates?  Making lots of repeated data is inefficient and you likely have some overarching goal in mind.  Sometimes there are better ways to get to the end goal

Comment: @BillWeiner My goal is to have a dataset that historical records for each policy. From there, I plan to calculate exposures (as the fraction of the year an observation period covers), join in mortality rates, and then calculate the expected death count for each row. After that, I plan to calculate the total number of deaths that actually occurred compared to the number of deaths we expected to occur for each year. We'll also want to summarize the data by a lot of different metrics as well, so that's why I'd like to have all the other fields included.

Comment: I think I get it - you have lots of calculations to perform and having the exploded dataset provides ease and flexibility in do this.

Comment: Added code to the answer to help clarify approaches

Comment: @BillWeiner Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this! Your examples were very helpful. I know this is kind of a weird thing to being doing with SQL, but we're trying to create this dataset each quarter, and then connect Tableau to it so our dashboards are updated automatically.

Comment: No worries, happy to.  A once a quarter SQL is less of a concern as to its performance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have a table with begin/end dates and you have a process for generating all the needed dates to span the min / max of these.  You want to apply this list of dates to the starting table to get all rows replicated between begin and end.

You have a good start - the list of dates.  The usual process is to join the dates with the table using inequality conditions. (ON dt >= begin and dt <= end)

You will need to deal with some edge condition around the unique dates for each input row.  If you need to maintain these unique dates you will need to fudge the join condition.  All doable.

==============================================================

Back from biz trip and can give more concrete guidance.

There's 2 ways to do this.  The first is the CTE approach you are driving down but this will pass all the data through each loop of the CTE.  This could be slow. This would look like (including data setup):

```
create table mytable (
  policy_number varchar(8), 
  issue_date timestamp, 
  termination_date timestamp,   
  issue_state varchar(4),   
  product varchar(16),  
  plan_code int);
  
insert into mytable values
('001', '1985-05-26',   '2005-03-02',   'CT',   'ROP',  123456),
('002', '1988-07-25',   '2005-08-07',   'CT',   'ROP',  654321)
;

with recursive pdata(policy_number, issue_date, termination_date, 
                     issue_state, product, plan_code, start_date, 
                     yr) as (
  select policy_number, issue_date, termination_date, issue_state,
  product, plan_code, issue_date as start_date, 0 as yr
  from mytable
  union all 
  select policy_number, issue_date, termination_date, issue_state,
    product, plan_code, 
    issue_date + yr * (interval '1 years') as start_date, 
    yr + 1 as yr
  from pdata
  where start_date < termination_date
)
select policy_number, issue_date, termination_date, 
       issue_state, product, plan_code, 
       case when start_date > termination_date
            then termination_date
            else start_date 
            end as start_date
from pdata
order by start_date, policy_number;
```

The other way to do this is to generate the length of years in the recursive CTE but apply the data expansion in a loop join.  This has the benefit of not carrying all the data through the recursive calls but has the expense of the loop join.  It should be faster with large amounts of data but you can decide which is right for you.

Since each input row has its own date I left things in year intervals as this is cleaner.  This looks like:

```
create table mytable (
  policy_number varchar(8), 
  issue_date timestamp, 
  termination_date timestamp,   
  issue_state varchar(4),   
  product varchar(16),  
  plan_code int);
  
insert into mytable values
('001', '1985-05-26',   '2005-03-02',   'CT',   'ROP',  123456),
('002', '1988-07-25',   '2005-08-07',   'CT',   'ROP',  654321)
;

with recursive nums(yr, maxnum) as (
  select 0::int as yr, 
    date_part('year', max(termination_date)) - 
      date_part('year', min(issue_date)) as maxnum
  from mytable
  union all 
  select yr + 1 as yr, maxnum
  from nums
  where yr <= maxnum
)
select policy_number, issue_date, termination_date, 
       issue_state, product, plan_code,
       case when issue_date + yr * interval '1 year' > termination_date
                then termination_date
                else issue_date + yr * interval '1 year' 
                end as start_date
from mytable p
left join nums n
on termination_date + interval '1 year' 
        > issue_date + yr * interval '1 year'
order by start_date, policy_number;
```